# Surge protector + mains power adapter safe?

Tags: mains, converter, adapter, surge-protection, plug

I was looking for a surge protected power strip/extension lead that could be mounted, have 6 or more outlets and came with a 5 meter mains cable with Type G (British plug) inlets and outlets. Having searched and searched I found no luck except with this product from Lanview, product no: LVR261875UK.

Having wasted the day searching for this very specific product, I put through my order hastily but overlooked something. According to the website I purchased it from, the power plug is Type F and not type G. I cross referenced with other websites, with the exact same product number, but they list it as Type G. It is difficult to corroborate visually as only the same 2 pictures are available on the web as far as I can see.

If the product is Type F mains rather than Type G I am loathed to return it as it does suit all of my requirements bar one. Having said that, is it at all safe or advisable to plug this surge protector into a Type F-to-Type G adapter and then plug it into the mains? As far as I am aware British and German mains are both 230 volts.

Comment: With a *proper* adapter it should be fine, but wouldn't it be a bit odd to have type G sockets and a type F plug when it's not meant to be an adapter? (For other non-Europeans: I looked it up, type G is the British plug and type F is the Schuko plug used in lots of european countries.)

Comment: maybe you are creating a problem where there is no problem

Comment: When you say "proper" adapter, do you mean one that isn't bought at the lowest price? Or is that an informal way of conveying a technical specification? Thanks for the answers so far.

Comment: Also, I checked Lanview's brochure and they list both inlets and outlets as Type G (British), so now I'm questioning if "Type F" was a mistake made by the third party seller.